# CSS selector for selecting elements relative to a specific element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do draw a colored border around the inputs by using css only.
I am not sure if it can be done with pure css, but maybe there is a css3 selector, that I have overseen?

Here's a mini-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsolti/rquf4kxh/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input class="error" value="red border"/><br/>
        <input id="1" value="green border"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="2" value="blue border"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`

.error { 
    border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

I want #1 to get a green border and #2 to have a blue border. Any ideas?
Again: no JS allowed :)

Important: only when the first input has class=error they should be colored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tsolti/rquf4kxh/)**

*CSS :*

```
.error { 
    border: 1px solid red;  
}

td input.error ~ input { 
    border:1px solid green;
}

td + td input { 
    border:1px solid pink;
}
```

**EDIT** after the question was edited including the condition that the colors should only be set when the `.error` class is set :

In the current HTML structure, you won't be able to target the last input with CSS only as is is not a sibling or a descendent of the `.error` element.

**workaround :**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/rquf4kxh/1/)**

Change the html markup so that both inputs are siblings of the `.error` input :

*HTML :*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="error" value="red border"/>
            <input value="green border"/>
            <input value="blue border"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So you can target them with the `+` sibling selector :

*CSS :*

```
.error { 
    border: 1px solid red;  
    display:block;
}

input.error+input { 
    border:1px solid green;
}
input.error+input+input { 
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: yes, but your second selector is not dependent on the error class

Comment: damn.. that's what I thought... well thanks for verifying it!

Comment: @ThomasSolti edited the answer : In the current html stucture, you won't be able to achieve your aim.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do like this?

```
input[value="red border"]{
   border: 1px solid red;
}
input[value="green border"]{
   border: 1px solid green;
}
input[value="blue border"]{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: sorry, no.. I edited the question and added: "only when the first input has class=error they should be colored." My bad! sorry